# Ocultar seta de navegação - Ionic

Tags: ionic, mobile

Boa Tarde

Estou com um problema e preciso saber como ocultar a setinha de voltar (navegação) em algumas paginas específicas, alguem tem alguma solução.
Desde já obrigado

Comment: Como você está navegando entre as páginas?

Answer (score 0):

acho que existem duas forma de ocultar o botão de back no Ionic uma delas é utilizando NavController quando você quiser ir para uma página sem back button utilize:

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(IrparaPaginaSemBackButton);
```

Outra forma é propio html da página tipo:

```
   <ion-navbar hideBackButton>
    <ion-title>Perfil</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

Onde a opção hideBackButton irá ocultar o botão automático do Ionic